# How to store node-red logs in local storage?

Tags: raspbian, node-red

I have setup node-red in Raspbian and I want to store the logs coming from node-red client in some storage place like .log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack to store node-red logs in linux distribution systems just follow the below steps:-

1. Create a custom node-red service in **/etc/systemd/system/** 
   Command to make a .service file `nano /etc/systemd/system/node-red-custom.service`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Node-RED is a tool for wiring together hardware devices, APIs and online services in new and interesting ways.
   After=syslog.target network.target
   Documentation=http://nodered.org/

   [Service]
   #Full Path to Node.js
   ExecStart=  /usr/bin/node-red
   WorkingDirectory=/root/node-red/
   # User/Group that launches node-RED (it's advised to create a new user for Node-RED)
   # You can do : sudo useradd node-red
   # then change the User=root by User=node-red
   User=root
   Group=root
   Nice=10
   #SyslogIdentifier=Node-RED
   SyslogIdentifier=node-red-custom
   StandardOutput=syslog
   StandardError=syslog
   # Make Node-RED restart if it fails
   Restart=on-failure
   # Node-RED need a SIGINT to be notified to stop
   KillSignal=SIGINT

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   2.Make configuration file which targets where do you want to store the logs

   **nano /etc/rsyslog.d/node-red-custom.conf**

   ```
   if $programname == 'node-red-custom' then /var/log/node-red-logs.log
   & stop
   ```

after creating these two file please run below commands

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
sudo systemctl enable node-red-custom.service
sudo systemctl start node-red-custom.service
```

Now your custom node-red service start storing logs in **/var/log/node-red-logs.log**

Note:- You must kill the running node-red service before enable the custom node-red service as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways this can be done.

1. Write a log function for the standard logging module. https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/logging
2. Use a third part node-red module to take care of logging to file. Something like -  https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-advance-logger

Answer (score 0):

The default install for Node-RED on raspbian will set it up as a service and the logs will be sent to syslog already.

The logs can be accesses withe the `node-red-log` tool or by using the `journalctrl` command